# Rotate left part of hex number in C++

Tags: c++, hex, bit-manipulation

I have the following problem : I have a hex number (datatype : std::uint64_t) in C++, and the hex number contains all the digits from 1 to a given n. The question is now to rotate the first k digits of the hex number, for example :

`hex = 0x436512, k = 3 --> 0x634512`

I have already tried splitting the hex number into two parts, e.g

```
std::uint64_t left = hex >> ((n - k) * 4);
std::uint64_t right = ((1UL << ((n - k) * 4)) - 1) & hex;
```

and then rotating `left` and merging `left` and `right` together. Is there a possibility to do this in-place and by only using bit-manipulation and/or mathematical operators?

Comment: How do you define `left` here? - the most significant non-zero nibble in the number, or what?

Comment: Do this in assembly language.  Most assembly languages have a rotate instruction and rotate through carry.

Comment: If it doesn't have to be fast, cheat like hell and convert to a string. [Rotate the characters you want rotated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate), and then convert back to a number.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You dont need assembly.  `__builtin_swap64` or `std::byteswap` (C++23) would do this. However there is no digit swap, only byte swap.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError `left` stores the the first 1 to k digits of `hex`, in the example I have shown earlier `left` would be equal to `0x436`

Comment: @user4581301 it has to be really fast, otherwise I wouldn't have used byte shifts in my code

Comment: I get that, but if the value was instead `0x36512`, would left 3 then be `365` as opposed to `036`? IOW, does the logic need to determine the magnitude of the most significant non-zero digit?

Comment: I'm starting to think @user4581301 is right: it's easiest to convert to text and back.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError the hex number doesn't even contain the number 0, it contains all digits from 1 to n (and 0x is not part of the number, it just means that the number is a hexadecimal number)

Comment: I like to bring up the stupid option. A lot of people waste a lot of time overcomplicating bits of code that didn't need it.

Comment: Are you rotating or reversing the first k digits?

Comment: BTW - there is no such thing as a 'hex number', decimal, binary, octal, hex.. only matters when a number is converted to a string

Answer (score 0):

As a baseline you can use this which is basically converting to digits and back.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>

uint64_t rotate( uint64_t value, int k ) {
    // decompose
    std::array<uint8_t,16> digits;
    int numdigits = 0;
    while ( value > 0 ) {
        digits[numdigits] = value % 16;
        value = value / 16;
        numdigits += 1;
    }
    if ( k>numdigits ) return 0;
    // revert digits
    int p1 = numdigits - 1;
    int p2 = numdigits - k;
    for ( ; p1>p2; p1--,p2++ ) {
        uint8_t tmp = digits[p1];
        digits[p1] = digits[p2];
        digits[p2] = tmp;
    }
    // reconstruct
    for ( int j=0; j<numdigits; ++j ) {
        value = (value*16) + digits[numdigits-1-j];
    }
    return value;
}

int main() {
    uint64_t value = 0x123ffffff;
    for ( int  j=0; j<8; ++j ) {
        value = value >> 4;
        printf( "%lx %lx\n", value, rotate(value,3) );
    }
}
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/77qWEo9vE

It produces:

```bash
Program stdout
123fffff 321fffff
123ffff 321ffff
123fff 321fff
123ff 321ff
123f 321f
123 321
12 0
1 0
```

You actually do not need to decompose the entire number, you can strictly decompose only the left digits.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>

uint64_t rotate( uint64_t value, int k ) {
    // sanity check
    if ( value == 0 ) return 0;

    // fast find number of digits
    int numdigits = (63-__builtin_clzl(value))/4 + 1;
    if ( k>numdigits ) return 0;

    // Decompose left and right
    int rightbits = 4*(numdigits-k);
    uint64_t left = value >> rightbits;
    uint64_t right = rightbits==0 ? 0 : value & (uint64_t(-1)>>(64-rightbits));


    // decompose left
    uint64_t rot = 0;
    for ( int j=0; j<k; ++j ) {
        uint64_t digit = left % 16;
        left = left / 16;
        rot = (rot*16) + digit;
    }
  
    // rejoin
    return right | (rot<<rightbits);
}

int main() {
    uint64_t value = 0x123ffffff;
    for ( int  j=0; j<8; ++j ) {
        value = value >> 4;
        printf( "%lx %lx\n", value, rotate(value,3) );
    }
}
```

Produces the same output.

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/P3z6W8b3M

Running under Google benchmark:

```cpp
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

uint64_t rotate1(uint64_t value, int k);
uint64_t rotate2(uint64_t value, int k);

struct RotateTrivial {
    uint64_t operator()(uint64_t value, int k) {
        return rotate1(value, k);
    }
};

struct RotateLeftOnly {
    uint64_t operator()(uint64_t value, int k) {
        return rotate2(value, k);
    }
};

template <typename Fn>
static void Benchmark(benchmark::State& state) {
    Fn fn;
    for (auto _ : state) {
        uint64_t value = uint64_t(-1);
        for (int j = 0; j < 16; ++j) {
            for (int k = 1; k < j; ++k) {
                uint64_t result = fn(value, k);
                benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result);
            }
            value = value >> 4;
        }
    }
}

BENCHMARK(Benchmark<RotateTrivial>);
BENCHMARK(Benchmark<RotateLeftOnly>);
BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

Produces on an AMD Threadripper 3960x 3.5GHz

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                          Time             CPU   Iterations
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark<RotateTrivial>         619 ns          619 ns      1158174
Benchmark<RotateLeftOnly>        320 ns          320 ns      2222098
```

Each iteration has 105 calls so it's about 6.3 ns/call or 20 cycles for the trivial version and 3.1ns/call or 10 cycles for the optimized version.